# NSTableView Biding with NSArrayController Not Work for Storyboard Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I follow guider from internet to binding NStableView use NSArrayController However seem it not work for me. Could you help. There're 3 problem:
1. Can't bind Content Array (you an see error (!))
2. Can't bind Value (from NStableview)
3. Can I add object without use pushbutton.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcRkF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31x5S.png)

Comment: Do you mean the gray `(!)` icon in the key path text field? That often shows because the editor doesn't know about all key paths, so it's not reliable.  What does happen when you execute? Where is `grade` defined? Did you try to add a breakpoint in the button's action and call methods on your `arrayController` manually from the debugger to see how it reacts?

Comment: This seems to be an old guide using a cell based table view. Find a guide using a view based table view. And maybe this helps: [Table View Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH1-SW1).

Comment: If you want to connect a button to the `add:` or `insert:` action of the array controller then "Prepares Content" of the array controller in IB should be switched on.

Answer (score 1):

1. The content array binding seems to be correct.
2. The table view binding is wrong.

   In the column select the `Table View Cell` (not `Table Cell View`!!) and bind the `Value` to `Table Cell View` > `objectValue.<property>` for example

   [image]

   Leave the Controller Key empty.
3. Yes you can, use an `IBOutlet` for the array controller and use the `NSArrayController` API to add objects.

Comment: 2.  Select the `Table View Cell` text field in the `Table Cell View` (not the `Table Column` or the `Text Cell`).

Comment: Thanks, however i follow the same still not work. When click add button there're still nothing happened.(ofcouse add button already sent action to arraycontroller.